# regarding uuencode and unix mailx command

Tags: unix

Why we have to use uuencode with unix mailx command to send email attachment.

I compressed one 50 mb file in unix to 22 mb using zip command. But when received in mail inbox using uuencode the file size got increased to 30 mb.

Can someone explain whats happenning here ot share the lunks which explains all these stuffs

Answer (score 0):

There's [RFC 5322 - Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322):

> #### 2.1.  General Description
>
> At the most basic level, a message is a series of characters.  A
> message that is conformant with this specification is composed of
> characters with values in the range of 1 through 127 and interpreted
> as US-ASCII [[ANSI.X3-4.1986](https://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc5322#ref-ANSI.X3-4.1986)] characters.  For
> brevity, this document    sometimes refers to this range of characters
> as simply "US-ASCII    characters".

To comply with RFC 5322, the mail is encoded so that it contains only US-ASCII    characters (the unencoded zip file would contain characters not in range 1 through 127). And the Wikipedia article [Uuencoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) explains the increase from 22 MB to 30 MB:

> Uuencoding takes 3 pre-formatted bytes and turns them into 4 and also
> adds begin/end tags, filename, and delimiters. This adds at least 33%
> data overhead compared to the source alone, though this can be at
> least somewhat compensated for by compressing the file before
> uuencoding it.